# How can I create an EF Code First data model for AdventureWorks2014?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, adventureworks

The fact that EF does not handle the `hierarchyid` MSSQL data type is widely known.  The problem using the AdventureWorks sample database to generate an EF data model caused by a table using `hierarchyid` is also quite well known and widely reported. A good proposed workaround, for read only scenarios, is to use a view in place of the 'offending' `Production.Document` table, and cast that column to a more acceptable type, like 'nvarchar'.

However, it seems the only avenue open for creating a Code First data model is to brutally remove the table altogether, as the EF Power Tools code generator skips the pleasantries allowing a user to select which tables to include in the model. So here, even using a view won't work, because the view depends on its base table.

Does anyone know a workaround for this that doesn't involve modifying the T4 templates by hard-coding to skip this table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, install VS 2013 Update 4, which include the latest EF Tools, and use the Code First Model from Database feature, it allows you to select which tables to generate.

Comment: As much as I'm dying to see what new and shiny things Update 4 brings, just deleting the table and restoring it after generating the code was a lot quicker than a 6GB download.